# How can I find hotels in a given area that rent units with a separate bedroom?

Tags: bookings, online-resources, hotels, accommodation-search-engines

I wonder how I can find hotels in a given area that rent units with a separate bedroom.

I unsuccessfully tried:

- https://agoda.com
- https://www.booking.com/
- http://maps.google.com/

but couldn't find such filters. I don't want to have to click on each hotel and read the room type descriptions to infer whether the hotel rents units with a separate bedroom.

---

Agoda has a "Number of bedrooms" filter but they put studio and 1 bedroom together:

[image]

Comment: For clarity, what do you mean by ‘unit with a separate bedroom’? A suite (bedroom & sitting room)? Two bedrooms with an interconnecting door? Searching ‘aparthotels’ might be worth a try?

Comment: @Traveller Thanks, I meant a suite (bedroom & sitting room).

Answer (score 13):

The industry term for what you're looking for is a **suite**, which typically means you get a separate living room and bedroom, although you need to do some due diligence: some hotels have single-room "studio suites". A one-bedroom suite is what you need.

Tripadvisor has a Suites filter under Amenities, and there's even a dedicated suites only search engine called [Suiteness](https://www.suiteness.com/).  That said, it's worth also looking into serviced apartments/Airbnb, which gets you a kitchen as well and are quite often more affordably priced.

---

Tripadvisor's Suites filter:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how do you activate the suite filter in Agoda? I couldn't find it. I just saw a "Number of bedrooms" filter but they put studio and 1 bedroom together.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Huh, Agoda popped in search as offering suites but looks like it's just a string match. Tripadvisor has an actual suite search though, I've updated the answer.

Comment: *Some* hotel suites include quite a useful kitchenette, but not all.

Comment: _Some_ hotel suites have separate rooms for the bed and living areas, but not all. Some suites are open plan.

Comment: @shoover Yes, that's why the first paragraph says you need to do due diligence to exclude marketing abominations like the "studio suite".